# Text gets on top of ripple effect in a custom layout for a preference

Tags: android, textview, android-preferences

I want to have a custom layout for a SwitchPreference for my settings. I can successfully change the layout to what I want but I have the following behaviour. The Text of this item is above the ripple effect the android has when you tap something.

[image: Preference]

Bellow we can se a simple version of the preference

```
<PreferenceCategory 
android:layout="settings_style_title"   
app:iconSpaceReserved="false">
    
    <SwitchPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="a_key"
    android:title="this text gets above the effect"
    android:layout="my_custom_layout" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

And my_custom_layout.

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical">
    
    <TextView   
    android:id="@android:id/title"      
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"       
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" 
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif" 
    android:minHeight="25dp" 
    android:scrollbars="none"
     android:singleLine="true" 
    android:textColor="#000000"  
    android:textSize="18sp"/>

   <Switch      
    android:id="@android:id/switch_widget"      
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"      
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I also tried using `android:widgetLayout` but this only controls the space that the widget is in and I can't give attributes to the `textview`.

Then I tried to give the attributes directly on the `SwitchPreference` and only use the `widgetLayout` but also did not work.

I also tried setting the title inside `my_custom_layout`.

I also tried removing the `android:background` but with no effect.

I think it has something to do with the layout because when I inspect them the preference without the `my_custom_layout` looks like this:

[image: without custom layout]

while the one with it looks like this:

[image: with custom layout]

Also what is the widget_frame? I cant seem to find anywhere to include it in `my_custom_layout` so I can have the same structure. Any thoughts?

Comment: Remove the background of your `TextView` if there is any.

Comment: @sajjad nice thought, I just did but with no effect. The text still remains on top and without the `android:background`.

Comment: Share the attributes of your `TextView` in the `xml` layout.

Comment: @Sajjad I just shared the `TextView` attributes and some more information.